# Israel immigration on work visa

Tags: israel

I wonder: when you enter Israel on a work visa (B1), what's the rules on (a) employment and (b) extension?

Is it anything like the USA system where your stay is initially tied to the employment with a sponsor company (hence if you leave your job you must find work with another H1-B sponsor quickly)? Or is it more like the EU system where any similar job with another company will do?

As for extension, is there ever the prospect of the temporary work visa status turning permanent, or even yielding Israeli nationality? Or is Jewish aliyah the only way to permanent citizenship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Israel doesn't have a process for employer-sponsored immigration. You can apply for Israeli citizenship after several years of being a permanent resident in Israel, but there's no explicit transition process from work visa to permanent residency as there is in the US.

The only ways to immigrate to Israel that are well-defined are through family (marrying an Israeli citizen and moving to live with him/her in Israel. Common-law and same-sex marriages/partnerships are recognized), or through conversion to Judaism and aliyah.

Comment: Actually there is such a process, but I think it's limited to home caregiving work (and perhaps some other cases I'm not aware of).

Comment: @einpoklum there's home caregiving employment visa, but it doesn't directly lead to permanent residency (a fact that many Israeli-born Philippino kids can tell you a lot about).

Comment: Indeed, I think it's a residence that's capped by max(5 years cumulative, end of your current employment). I still think it's worth mentioning this partial exception to the rule.

Comment: Your first paragraph appears to contradict your second?